# How can I fix the TypeError of my dataclass in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass with 5 attributes. When I give these attributes via a dictionary, it works well. But when the dictionary has more attributes than the class have, the class gives TypeError. I am trying to make that when there is extra values, the class wouldn't care them. How can I make that?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Employee(object):
    name: str
    lastname: str
    age: int or None
    salary: int
    department: str

    def __new__(cls, name, lastname, age, salary, department):
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __post_init__(self):
        if type(self.age) == str:
            self.age = int(self.age) or None

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.lastname}, {self.age}' 

dic = {"name":"abdülmutallip", 
"lastname":"uzunkavakağacıaltındauzanıroğlu", 
"age":"24", "salary":2000, "department":"İK", 
"city":"istanbul", "country":"tr", "adres":"yok", "phone":"0033333"}

a = Employee(**dic)
print(a)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'city'
```

I want the class works properly in this situation without any error. I don't want to add these extra attributes into the class.

Comment: Why add `__new__` *at all*, a dataclass doesn't need an explicit `__new__` method.  `int or None` is not a valid way of describing that `age` is optional, use `Optional[age]` and assign a default value. Optional values have to follow required fields.

Comment: Is `age` supposed to be *optional*, or did you just want to record that it'll be set to `None` if `age=0` is supplied?

Comment: I'd like to know why age could be `None`? Every employee should have an age and if you mean that the age may be uninitialized, maybe it makes more sense to use `age = -1`.

Comment: @ShaiAvr: no, `None` is an excellent choice for *age is missing*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters For something like age, I'd prefer `-1` because it's clearly an invalid age, but I suppose it's personal preference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one ignore extra arguments passed to a data class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678337/how-does-one-ignore-extra-arguments-passed-to-a-data-class)

Comment: The matter is not age's type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the dataclass to accept arbitrary extra keyword arguments then you either have to define your own `__init__` method, or provide a custom `__call__` method on a [*metaclass*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses). If you define a custom `__init__` method, the `dataclass` decorator won't generate one for you; at this point there is no need to use `__post_init__` any more either since you already are writing an `__init__` method.

Side notes:

- `__new__` can't alter what arguments are passed to `__init__`. The metaclass's `__call__` will normally first call `cls.__new__(<arguments>)` then call `instance.__init__(<arguments>` on the `instance` return value from `__new__`, see the [datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).
- You can't use `int or None`, that's an expression that just returns `int`, it won't let you omit the `age` parameter. Give the field a default value instead, or use a `Union` type hint if `None` is only used to indicate age=0 or a failed `int()` conversion.
- Fields that have a default defined **must** come after fields that do not have a default defined, so put `age` at the end.
- If you also use type hinting beyond dataclasses, and `age` is meant to be an optional field, then use [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) to properly mark the type of the `age` field as optional. `Optional[int]` is equivalent to `Union[int, None]`; personally I prefer the latter in constructors when there is no default value set and *omitting* `age` is not acceptable.
- Use `isinstance()` to determine if an object is a string. Or *just don't test*, since `int(self.age)` just returns `self.age` unchanged if it already is set to an integer.
- Only use `or None` in the `__post_init__` method if it is okay for an age set to `0` to be set to `None`.
- If `age` is to be set to `None` only if `int(age)` fails, then you have to use `try:...except` to handle the `ValueError` or `TypeError` exceptions that `int()` can raise in that case, not `or None`.

Assuming that you meant for `age` to be set to `None` only if conversion fails:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union

@dataclass
class Employee(object):
    name: str
    lastname: str
    age: Union[int, None]  # set to None if conversion fails
    salary: int
    department: str

    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        lastname: str,  
        age: Union[int, None],
        salary: int,
        department: str,
        *args: Any,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        try:
            self.age = int(age)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            # could not convert age to an integer
            self.age = None
        self.salary = salary
        self.department = department

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.lastname}, {self.age}'
```

If you want to go the metaclass route, then you can create one that ignores all extra arguments for almost *any* class, by introspecting the `__init__` or `__new__` method call signature:

```
from inspect import signature, Parameter

class _ArgTrimmer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_args, self.new_kw = [], {}
        self.dispatch = {
            Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY: self.pos_only,
            Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY: self.kw_only,
            Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: self.pos_or_kw,
            Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL: self.starargs,
            Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD: self.starstarkwargs,
        }

    def pos_only(self, p, i, args, kwargs):
        if i < len(args):
            self.new_args.append(args[i])

    def kw_only(self, p, i, args, kwargs):
        if p.name in kwargs:
            self.new_kw[p.name] = kwargs.pop(p.name)

    def pos_or_kw(self, p, i, args, kwargs):
        if i < len(args):
            self.new_args.append(args[i])
            # drop if also in kwargs, otherwise parameters collide
            # if there's a VAR_KEYWORD parameter to capture it
            kwargs.pop(p.name, None)
        elif p.name in kwargs:
            self.new_kw[p.name] = kwargs[p.name]

    def starargs(self, p, i, args, kwargs):
        self.new_args.extend(args[i:])

    def starstarkwargs(self, p, i, args, kwargs):
        self.new_kw.update(kwargs)

    def trim(self, params, args, kwargs):
        for i, p in enumerate(params.values()):
            if i:  # skip first (self or cls) arg of unbound function
                self.dispatch[p.kind](p, i - 1, args, kwargs)
        return self.new_args, self.new_kw

class IgnoreExtraArgsMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.__new__ is not object.__new__:
            func = cls.__new__
        else:
            func = getattr(cls, '__init__', None)
        if func is not None:
            sig = signature(func)
            args, kwargs = _ArgTrimmer().trim(sig.parameters, args, kwargs)
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This metaclass will work for any Python class, but if you were to subclass in a built-in type then the `__new__` or `__init__` methods may not be introspectable. Not the case here, but a caveat that you would need to know about if you were to use the above metaclass in other situations.

Then use the above as a `metaclass` parameter on your dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union

@dataclass
class Employee(metaclass=IgnoreExtraArgsMeta):
    name: str
    lastname: str
    age: Union[int, None]
    salary: int
    department: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        try:
            self.age = int(self.age)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            # could not convert age to an integer
            self.age = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.lastname}, {self.age}'
```

The advantage of using a metaclass should be clear here; no need to repeat all the fields in the `__init__` method.

Demo of the first approach:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> from typing import Union
>>> @dataclass
... class Employee(object):
...     name: str
...     lastname: str
...     age: Union[int, None]  # set to None if conversion fails
...     salary: int
...     department: str
...     def __init__(self,
...         name: str,
...         lastname: str,
...         age: Union[int, None],
...         salary: int,
...         department: str,
...         *args: Any,
...         **kwargs: Any,
...     ) -> None:
...         self.name = name
...         self.lastname = lastname
...         try:
...             self.age = int(age)
...         except (ValueError, TypeError):
...             # could not convert age to an integer
...             self.age = None
...         self.salary = salary
...         self.department = department
...     def __str__(self):
...         return f'{self.name}, {self.lastname}, {self.age}'
... 
>>> dic = {"name":"abdülmutallip",
... "lastname":"uzunkavakağacıaltındauzanıroğlu",
... "age":"24", "salary":2000, "department":"İK",
... "city":"istanbul", "country":"tr", "adres":"yok", "phone":"0033333"}
>>> a = Employee(**dic)
>>> a
Employee(name='abdülmutallip', lastname='uzunkavakağacıaltındauzanıroğlu', age=24, salary=2000, department='İK')
>>> print(a)
abdülmutallip, uzunkavakağacıaltındauzanıroğlu, 24
>>> a.age
24
>>> Employee(name="Eric", lastname="Idle", age="too old to tell", salary=123456, department="Silly Walks")
Employee(name='Eric', lastname='Idle', age=None, salary=123456, department='Silly Walks')
```

and of the second approach:

```
>>> @dataclass
... class Employee(metaclass=IgnoreExtraArgsMeta):
...     name: str
...     lastname: str
...     age: Union[int, None]
...     salary: int
...     department: str
...     def __post_init__(self):
...         try:
...             self.age = int(self.age)
...         except (ValueError, TypeError):
...             # could not convert age to an integer
...             self.age = None
...     def __str__(self):
...         return f'{self.name}, {self.lastname}, {self.age}'
...
>>> a = Employee(**dic)
>>> print(a)
abdülmutallip, uzunkavakağacıaltındauzanıroğlu, 24
>>> a
Employee(name='abdülmutallip', lastname='uzunkavakağacıaltındauzanıroğlu', age=24, salary=2000, department='İK')
>>> Employee("Michael", "Palin", "annoyed you asked", salary=42, department="Complaints", notes="Civil servants should never be asked for their salary, either")
Employee(name='Michael', lastname='Palin', age=None, salary=42, department='Complaints')
```

If `age` is meant to be optional (so, have a default value), then move it to the end of the fields, give it `Optional[int]` as the type, and assign `None` to it. You'll have to do the same in the `__init__` method you specify your own:

```
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Employee(object):
    name: str
    lastname: str
    age: Optional[int] = None
    salary: int
    department: str

    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        lastname: str,  
        salary: int,
        department: str,
        age: Optional[int] = None,
        *args: Any,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        # ...
```

Comment: This will still fail if you provide more arguments than expected. You should add `*args` and `**kwargs` to `__init__` to make it work like the OP wanted. As a side note: `Optional[int]` is better than `Union[int, None]`

Comment: @ShaiAvr: `Optional[int]` states that `age` has a default value if you omit it. I explicitly want to document this as **not being optional**.

Comment: @ShaiAvr: and oops, I had forgotten including the `*args, **kwargs` arguments in the `__init__`. Fixed now.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional), `Optional[int]` is equivalent to `Union[int, None]` and it's not related to default values.

Comment: @ShaiAvr: `Optional[int]` is indeed the equivalent, I'm just being explicit about it here. It is a personal preference.

Comment: Is there any other way to make that without using normal __init__ ?

Comment: @EmrahTema: I'm not sure what you are asking there. I showed you your two options, I am not aware of any others.

Comment: Note: It might make sense to use `operator.index` instead of `int` to perform the `self.age` conversion/verification. The type annotation says "must be int or None", but using `int` to convert will coerce non-`int`-like things to `int` (e.g. `str`s that look like numbers, `float`/`Decimal`/`Fraction` causing truncation). `operator.index` is more conservative; it accepts `int` (and its subclasses) and things that can be losslessly converted to `int` only, returning an `int` (or subclass thereof), matching the type annotation more closely.

Comment: @ShadowRanger note that the OP is passing in a string for the age; it appears they are at that to be acceptable. At which point the `__init__` method signature type for `age` really should differ from the instance field type. That’s not something that dataclasses can cater for however.

Comment: So if type hinting is to be supported properly, the proper way to handle this is to use a separate factory method on the class which then is type hinted accordingly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Good point. A factory method that performs more liberal conversions, with strict conversions on the class itself, is probably the correct solution; as is, static type checkers should flag the OP's code, even if it happens to run without error.